# IpRestrictionModule - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

After trying multiple configuration changes, I cannot seem to get past this error. This is a fresh install of Windows Server 2012R2, with all of the options selected under the ASP.NET/IIS modules and features selected. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and the target framework is 4.5

I have also executed the following commands:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
-commit:apphost
```

to the command, like this

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity -commit:apphost
```

so that the unlocking is applied at the topmost (applicationhost.config) level instead of the lower web.config levels

Comment: I have tried added the -commit:apphost to all of the commands, and then an IISReset. Still getting the same error

Comment: upon further investigation, there was a section of improperly formatted xml in the web.config that caused the issue to persist